# Distance between arrow and reaction product

Tags: arrows, chemfig

Please tell me, How I can reduce a distance between arrow and feed substances. I want the same distances at all three directions. To make it clearer, I explain:
I drew the side substances as a massive elements in order to the scheme acquired roundness. To get a nice scheme. 
In my opinion each of the array elements has a rectangular invisible borders which can not overlap with an arrows, so the lower elements have lager distances between arrows than the upper.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\setchemrel{}{}{3em}
\noindent
\schemestart
\chemfig{%
**6(------)
}
\arrow{<=>}[90]
\chemfig{%
*6(---
    ([,,,,draw=none]-([,,,,draw=black]*6(--
        ([,,,,draw=none]-([:-18,,,,draw=black]*5(----(-)-)))
    ----)))
-(-)--)
}
\arrow(@c1--){<=>}[210]
\chemfig{%
**6(-
    ([,,,,draw=none]-([,,,,draw=black]**6(-(-)---
        ([,,,,draw=none]-([,,,,draw=black]**6(-(-)--(-)---)))
    --)))
----*6(--)-)
}
\arrow(@c1--){<=>}[330]
\chemfig{%
-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]
-[:-90,,,,draw=none]-[:210,,,,draw=black]-[:150]-[:210]-[:150]-[:210]
-[:-90,,,,draw=none](-[:210]-[:150])-[:-30,,,,draw=black]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]
}
\schemestop
\caption{Reforming} \label{fig:Precursors}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A small, unrelated tip: [use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` in a figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2652/32374). Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “problem” is empty space. The arrows actually are not far away from what `chemfig` sees as compound. You can verify this by adding `\schemedebug{true}`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \schemedebug{true}
  \setatomsep{1.5em}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{**6(------)}
    \arrow{<=>}[90]
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{*6(----(-)--)}
      \arrow{0}[20,.3]
      \chemfig{*6(------)}
      \arrow{0}[-30,.2]
      \chemfig{*5(---(-)--)}
    }
    \arrow(@c1--){<=>}[210]
    \null
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{-[:30]**6(--(-)----)}
      \arrow{0}[-90,.3]
      \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]**6(------)}
      \arrow{0}[-40,.1]
      \chemfig{-[:-30]**6(------)}
    }
    \arrow(@c1--){<=>}[330]
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]}
      \arrow{0}[-120,.1]
      \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]}
      \arrow{0}[-130,.4]
      \chemfig{-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]}
    }
  \schemestop
  \caption{Reforming} \label{fig:Precursors}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible idea (which uses the subschemes that I used for the clusters of molecules with single `\chemfig`'s for each molecule): connect the center and the surroundings with shortened invisible arrows and latter connect the center with specific molecules in the clusters. (I also scaled all molecules by using e reduced atom-sep (`\setatomsep{1.5em}`).)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \schemedebug{true}
  \setatomsep{1.5em}
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{**6(------)}
    \arrow{<=>}[90]
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{*6(----(-)--)}
      \arrow{0}[20,.3]
      \chemfig{*6(------)}
      \arrow{0}[-30,.2]
      \chemfig{*5(---(-)--)}
    }
    \arrow(@c1--){0}[210,.1]% invisible
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{-[:30]**6(--(-)----)}
      \arrow{0}[-90,.3]
      \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]**6(------)}
      \arrow{0}[-40,.1]
      \chemfig{-[:-30]**6(------)}
    }
    \arrow(@c1--){0}[330,.1]% invisible
    \subscheme{
      \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]}
      \arrow{0}[-120,.1]
      \chemfig{-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30](-[:90])-[:-30]}
      \arrow{0}[-130,.4]
      \chemfig{-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]-[:-30]-[:30]}
    }
    % connect with arrows:
    \arrow(@c1--@c8){<=>}
    \arrow(@c1--@c12){<=>}
  \schemestop
  \caption{Reforming} \label{fig:Precursors}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, in this case the substances are closer to the arrows. But I drew the side substances as a massive elements in order to the scheme acquired roundness. To get a nice scheme. In my opinion each of the array elements can not overlap with an arrow, so the lower elements have lager distances between arrows than the upper.

Comment: You should have mentioned that requirement in your question. I'll revise my answer in a bit...

Comment: And of course I do not know how to make the scheme a little less. It goes abroad. This is another problem.

Comment: @EvgenyChem I edited the answer

Comment: Great, thank you. This is much better. Now I will understand.